# Rider for Outlook Web App (OWA)?

Tags: outlook-addin, jetbrains-ide, visual-studio-addins, outlook-web-app, rider

Is it possible to work with JetBrains Rider to develop OWA addin ? Maybe a plugin to add ?

I work with Visual Studio 2017 and when I run my project, Outlook is launched with my addin added. I would do the same with Rider.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the command-line of Outlook started in VS and recreate the same command in Executable run configuration in Rider.